# a fixed point for fix :: Eq a => (a -> a) -> a -> a

Tags: haskell, fixpoint-combinators

Hello  everyone I'm trying to implement the higher-order function fix, which computes an [attractive fixed point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed_point_(mathematics)#Attractive_fixed_points) of an arbitrary function `f :: a -> a` from an initial point `x`. That is, a fixed point of the form `fᴷ(x)` for a given `f` and `x`.

```
-- CONTRACT
fix :: Eq a => (a -> a) -> a -> a
-- DEFINITION [TODO: Implement fix]
fix f x  = ?
```

My current attempt is:

```
fix f x | f x == x = x
        | otherwise = fix f x
    where x = f x
```

**Note: Your
function will not terminate if the function does not converge from the starting
point**.
can someone help me please ? I tried but it didn't return anything

Comment: Can you share your attempt?

Comment: fix f x
        | f x == x = x
        | otherwise = fix f x
        where x = f x

Comment: The type of your function is wrong. The fixed point combinator has the type `fix :: (a -> a) -> a`.

Comment: @AaditMShah It's a fine signature, it's just a different `fix` than the one PL folks like so much.

Comment: no it's not wrong . it's a homework !!

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but maybe you're interested in a one-liner: `fix = until=<<((==)=<<)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A common misconception is that when you write `x = ...`, you *assign* a value in Haskell. In Haskell one does *not* assign a value, one *declares* one.

This thus means that basically you constructed a variable `x` in the `where` clause that is *not* the `x` in the head of the function, so something like:

```
fix :: Eq a => (a -> a) -> a -> a
fix f _ | f x == x = x
        | otherwise = fix f x
    where x = f x
```

Here you thus defined `x` in terms of itself: `x = f x`, so that means if Haskell aims to evaluate that, it will start calculating `f(f(f(f(f(f(...))))))`, but without any checks if the *fixed point* has been reached.

The solution is thus to introduce a new variable, for example `x2`, and thus use this like:

```
fix :: Eq a => (a -> a) -> a -> a
fix f x | x == x2 = x
        | otherwise = fix f x2
    where x2 = f x
```

So here `x2` is the next `x`. Given `x == x2`, we return `x` (or `x2`), if not, we calculate the fixed point of `f` and `x2`, so we advanced one step in the "*Quest for the fixed point*".

Comment: it doesn't work either returns an wrong answer or it returns nothing :\\     Ihave typed fix (*2)3 it should return 12 but it returns nothing .

Comment: @Amerov: why is the fixed point of `(*2)` `3`? The idea of a fixed point is `f x == x`, but `(*2) 12 == 24`, not `12`.

Comment: @Amerov the fixed point of (*2) is 0, and it's not attractive, so it won't be reached for any argument that's not 0 to begin with.

Comment: @WillNess can you give me an example please   just to know how to use it or how it works

Comment: @Amerov `fix (*2) 0` would work. or e.g. ``fix (`div` 2) 100``. Or `let collatz x | even x = div x 2 | x <= 1 = 1 | otherwise = (3*x+1)` and then `fix collatz 99`.

Comment: @WillNess does it work on String if the argument is a string

Comment: @Amerov yes, why not? `String` is an instance of `Eq` alright. You just need to devise a function of String to String which has an (attractive) fixed point.

Comment: `fix reverse ""` does work. `""` is a non-attractive fixed point of reverse. also, `fix reverse "12321"` works.

Comment: try `fix cos 1` to find the Dottie number.

Answer (score 4):

Give a different name to the next step of iteration, like this:

```
where x' = f x
```

(instead of `where x = f x`). Now review the rest of your existing code, and for each occurrence of `x`, ask yourself: did I mean `x` here, or `x'`?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `where x' = f x'`?

Comment: @AaditMShah: no, since then you recursively call the fix point, without doing a proper equality check.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem No you don't. Haskell is lazy.

Comment: @AaditMShah: I know that, but again, the fixed point, like the one defined in the library is related to this one, but not the same one. The `fix` in the library, is more if you have `f`s that emit something, for example `f = (1:)`, in order to generate an infinite list of `1`s.

Comment: It is not because Haskell is lazy, that `x' = f x`, is just equivalent to `x' = f x`.

Answer (score 4):

You already have answers on how to write`fix` from scratch. If you'd like to try it using some standard Haskell functions, I suggest you look at the function `until`.

```
until :: (a -> Bool) -> (a -> a) -> a -> a
```

Note the type of `until` is rather similar to the one you want. It just takes one extra argument of the form `a -> Bool`. The expression `until p f x` iteratively applies `f` starting with the initial point `x`, until some condition `p` is satisfied. And you should easily be able to write `fix` in the form,

```
fix = until p
```

for some function `p :: a -> Bool`. Now you just need to implement this stopping condition `p`, which checks if a point `y` you've calculated is a fixed point of `f`, that is if `f y == y`.